# SSHJ Example of Public Key Auth from File

Tags: java, file, public-key, sshj

Can someone give me an example of using SSHJ for Public Key Authentication? I realise this question is essentially identical to [ssh example of private/public key authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686710/sshj-example-of-private-public-key-authentication), however the answer by the author https://stackoverflow.com/users/126346/shikhar refers to a google user group that no longer exists, and I am having trouble getting it to work.

Thanks!
Phil

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We built the [overthere framework](https://github.com/xebialabs/overthere/) on top of SSHJ. Which can connect also connect using key files.
The following piece of code should work, but make sure you add the bouncycastle library to your classpath.

```
SSHClient client = new SSHClient();
String username = "johndoe";
File privateKey = new File("~/.ssh/id_rsa");
KeyProvider keys = client.loadKeys(privateKey.getPath());
client.authPublickey(username, keys);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding! Is this definitely your code? I attempted to code it and got the error that SSHClient.loadKeys doesn't accept a file as an argument, which according to http://schmizz.net/sshj/javadoc/0.5.0/net/schmizz/sshj/SSHClient.html is correct. I have previously tried providing location as a string to loadKeys, to no avail. Am I misreading your code?

Comment: I forgot to add the getPath(). Stripped quite a bit of framework code to give you a concise answer ;)

Comment: Alas, that's essentially what I did, and it did not work. I have given up on SSHJ for now, using JSch instead, as it seems to provide equivalent functionality, but that I can actually get working. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you elaborate on what part of it didn't work? Exceptions? error messages?

Comment: Using code above, i got error `Could not verify 'ssh-rsa' host key with fingerprint '<fingerprint>' for '<hostname>' on port <22>`.   When I added line `client.addHostKeyVerifier(new PromiscuousVerifier());`, i get `Exhausted available authentication methods`.

Comment: Using debug logging you should see which authentication methods it tries. Is your server setup for private key authentication?

Comment: should be `client.authPublickey` with lower case 'k' :)

Comment: don't forget to add the `client.connect("199.xxx.xxx.xxx", port);` line before `client.authPublickey(username, keys);` or you will  not connect...

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue as well. I ended up changing

```
client.authPublickey(user, "id_rsa.pub")
```

to

```
client.authPublickey(user, client.loadKeys("id_rsa"))
```